# Projective space in algebraic geometry vs topology and inductive construction

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is the pushout of

$$\mathbb P^n \leftarrow \mathbb A^{n+1}-\{(0,..,0)\} \rightarrow \mathbb A^{n+1}$$

in the category of varieties? I know for topological spaces that the pushout of

$$\mathbb {RP}^n \leftarrow  S^{n} \rightarrow  D^{n+1}$$

is $\mathbb {RP}^{n+1}$ but I don't think that this holds for varieties.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not clear that this pushout exists in the category of schemes.